# How to delete this div in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When the button is clicked I want an area to write an e-mail. And when the delete icon is clicked, this area is deleted. How can i do

```
addListItem = () => {
        var number=0;
        var list = [...this.state.list];
        number++;
        var ele=
        <div id={number}>
            <span>{number}
                <TextField id="standard-basic" style={{width:"60%"}}></TextField>
            </span>
            <IconButton>
                <Delete></Delete>
            </IconButton>
        </div>
        list.push(ele)
        this.setState({list})
    }

<Button onClick={this.addListItem} style={{ float : "left" ,marginTop:10,backgroundColor: "#657c9e", borderRadius: 4, boxShadow: "#727272", width: 159, height: 46 , color: Color.AIRPLATFORM.WHITE , fontSize: 15 , fontWeight: 500,marginLeft:0}} variant="contained">ADD</Button><br></br><br></br><br></br>

<div id="list" style={{backgroundColor:"#ffffff",borderRadius:16,padding:10,minHeight:140,width:406,borderRadius:8,marginTop:10,boxShadow: "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14)"}}>
                                            {this.state.list}
                                        </div>
```

Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rendering. So, what conditional rendering is, you render the JSX element based on a condition.

#### Conditional rendering

```
{condition ? <p>True</p> : <p>False</p>}
```

This one will render True paragraph if condition is ture, and False paragraph if condition is false

```
{condition && <p>True</p>}
```

This one will render True only if condition is True, and render nothing otherwise

### In your case

In your case, first you need a state variable to store the render choice

```
const [renderDelete, setRenderDelete] = useState(true)
```

Then, on click you set renderDelete to false:

```
<button onClick={() => setRenderDelete(false)> Render Delete </button>
```

Lastly, you conditional render based on the `renderDelete` variable:
Instead of `<Delete />` you render:

```
   {renderDelete && <Delete />}
```

You can do the same logic to toggle between rendering Edit field or Delete field:

```
 {renderDelete ? <Delete /> : <Edit />}
```

Comment: Actually i have a delete button.I just want to delete current div when the clicked delete button. <div id={number}> this div

Comment: *deleteing the current div* is actually just not rendering it. You have to conditional render the whole delete div, and when you click the button you simply set the condition to false